# Encoding Swift Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, encode

I am attempting to store a Swift array in `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder` but I am getting the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Int?]' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'

How can I store the array? Do I have to convert it to an `NSArray`?

```
public var imageViewsImageVersion: [Int?] = []

override public func encodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeObject(imageViewsImageVersion, forKey: "imageViewsImageVersion")
}
```

Comment: cast the array to AnyObject: coder.encodeObject(imageViewsImageVersion as AnyObject, forKey: "imageViewsImageVersion"). then when you decode you cast it back to an array

Comment: That compiles but crashes with `Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array<Swift.Optional<Swift.Int>>' (0x1203f72e8) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x11ff23040).`

Comment: what happens if you remove the optional from Int?

Comment: Umm, well I need it that way for a reason.

Comment: well I just wanted to confirm that its the optional that is causing the problem

Comment: That works and doesn't even need to be cast to AnyObject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130821/discussion-between-justinm-and-jeshua-lacock).